# Super weird boot behaviour

Tags: boot, screen

My PC Ubuntu 18.04 may take HOURS to show a screen. Literally. The longer I leave it off, the longer it takes to restart. I’ve tried commands like suspend, hibernate and rtcwake to go around this, to no avail.

After one or two hours with the PC on, I notice that Ubuntu is actually running, but not showing. I can, for instance, blindly type my password, then type a command to turn it off or restart it, and it does.

So Ubuntu *is* there after one or two hours.

Sometimes, I unplug the SSD and it takes the same amount of time to show anything on the screen. However, WHAT it shows *without the SSD* is sometimes a lot of lines of Ubuntu code, even though there’s no SSD and therefore no OS.

I thought there might be a problem with the CPU (Intel Core i5), which has integrated graphics, so I have bought and installed a new CPU.

The same (non-)behaviour repeats itself. However ‒and this is really weird‒ without the SSD (that is, no OS), after some time the screen shows Ubuntu’s first screen with my username, asking for a password.

?!?!?!?!?

The next step would be to get a new motherboard, but now I’m beginning to wonder whether this has anything to do with Ubuntu itself, and not with some hardware.
It doesn’t make much sense, though, as the screen shows *nothing* for ages, not even the BIOS first screen.

What’s going on? Before I commit more money towards a new MoBo, could this be fixed through Ubuntu?

Comment: Do you get the same behavior of you boot from the installation USB and use the try Ubuntu option? If so, this is a hardware problem

Comment: Do you have more than one disk on this PC? What make/model # PC? Desktop or laptop? If you enter the BIOS, what disks does it see... maybe a SSD AND a HDD? Reset the Power Manager by turning off the PC, then hold down the Power button for about 30 seconds. See if that makes any difference. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @user68186 Thanks. Hadn’t thought of that. Yes, indeed. This morning, after 7 hours off, my PC won’t start through a flash drive, though it did last night, when the system was “hot”. 
The next plausible culprit is the monitor, then the MoBo.

Comment: Whatever the problem, I’m puzzled about the lines of Ubuntu code appearing (and, once or twice, even the initial “password” screen, with my username on). Do these remain in the RAM sticks even after the PC is off? Shouldn’t they have been wiped out? Even so, shouldn’t the BIOS do *nothing* if it can’t find an OS, instead of looking for booting code in the RAM?

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your interest! After the test suggested above by user 68186, I don’t think it’s anything to do with the SSD. I've tested a different monitor, which works all right, BUT I've also had to take out one of the RAM sticks.

Comment: Don't randomly start connecting/disconnecting various pieces of hardware helter skelter. Have a reason and a plan. Do you have answers for my earlier questions?

Comment: @heynnema I have an SSD and an HDD. I did what you suggested (hold the power button for 30”), and there was no change. Last night, I programmed rtcwake for 6.30am. The PC did wake, but no screen until 10am. Strongly suspect it’s some capacitor taking ages to get charged in the monitor. Am considering ordering a new monitor, as I’m pretty far from any tech shop right now. Using laptop when there’s no PC monitor. I’ve ordered two new RAM sticks of the same brand (they’re different brands right now) as Linux Memtest86 gets stuck when testing both together.

Comment: @Pabzum Does the computer boot normally if one or the other RAM stick is removed?

Comment: @heynnema It doesn't. Tonight, I'm going to unplug the hard drives and leave only the flash drive with the Linux demo. Then I’ll do an rtcwake for 6am tomorrow (I start work at 8am). This is to check how it behaves without the hard drives −that is, ff there’s no power outage during the night (it often happens around here; in fact, the problem may have been started by a power surge after an outage).

Again, thank you for your interest!